# Webpack, bootstrap 5 $(...).modal

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-5

I am migrating my (Legacy) web project to webpack and I have the basic working with Bootstrap 5 CSS. But, I am not able to use Bootstrap JS APIs in my JS files, all I get is this errors even if bootstrap is imported.

```
$(...).modal is not a function
```

This is a legacy serverside html template project, so I run watch to compile into js files that are included serverside. Can anyone point me to why I cannot get bootstrap JS working?

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        registration_form_checkout: {
            import: './js-css/RegistrationForm/checkout.page.js'
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static/dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: require.resolve('jquery'),
            jQuery: require.resolve('jquery'),
            Popper: ['popper.js','default'],
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    autoprefixer
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                rules: [{
                    test: /\.woff2?$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

JS-code (./js-css/RegistrationForm/checkout.page.js):

```
import './styles.scss'


require('bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css');
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

$('#staticBackdrop').modal()
```

JQuery works fine, so I am able to use jquery inside the checkout.page.js, but bootstrap will not work.

Any help for a webpack newbie?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989175/how-do-i-load-the-bootstrap-5-jquery-plugins-in-an-es6-project-using-webpack).

Comment: Thanks, assigning jquery to windows did make it progress:

```
window.jQuery = $;
console.log($("#staticBackdrop"));
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
import {getjQuery} from "bootstrap/js/src/util";
console.log(getjQuery());
$('#staticBackdrop').modal()
```

´getjQuery()` is not longer null, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I think it's an issue about jquery in webpack. Look at [my answer for a jquery plugin with  Vite et Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74039112/10489562). The parts about jquery could be pasted to solve your issue with webpack.

Comment: It seems to be loading of bootstrap, even withouth JQuery it fails, eg:

```
const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('staticBackdrop'), {
    keyboard: false
})
```

Gives: ncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Modal')